# How to Get "Everyone except external users" from Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am working on a task that requires me to get "Everyone except external users" group from Sharepoint Online using c#.

few articles that i found online mentioned that i must be using "c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/$authRealm" to get "Everyone except external users". ofcourse getting the $authRealm guid has additonal steps.

but i found out **clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("Everyone except external users");** worked just fine. I found the same user.

Is using clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("Everyone except external users"); enough? or am i missing something?

I am learning sharepoint so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code below to get "Everyone except external users".

```
$siteUrl = "https://sharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/subsite"

# Set headers
$headers = @{
    "Authorization"="Bearer ";
}

$authRealm = "";
# Make an invalid request. We will extract the GUID from the Response.
try {
    Invoke-WebRequest $("$siteUrl/_vti_bin/client.svc") -Method POST -Headers $headers
}
catch [exception] {
    # Extract Authentication Realm GUID from Response headers
    $_.Exception.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] -match '(?<=Bearer realm=")\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+(?=")'
    $authRealm = $matches[0];
}

$everyoneExceptExternal = "c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/$authRealm"
$everyoneExceptExternalPrincipal = $web.EnsureUser($everyoneExceptExternal);
$ctx.Load($everyoneExceptExternalPrincipal);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Reference**: https://gist.github.com/davehax/bf60c002bd58faf65f067cf8e27f422d#file-geteveryoneexceptexternalusersprincipal-ps1